# How to make a good pattern to control multiple requests dependency by using Alamofire? Such as request2 need request1's response

Tags: ios, swift, request, dependencies, alamofire

I use Alamofire to send multiple requests at the same time. But the request A need request B's response named token. I will give a example :

```
var token = "111111111111"

let URLString1 = "http://httpbin.org/get?token=\(token)"
Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString1, parameters:  nil, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success(let JSON):
        print("http1: \(JSON)")
        token = "22222222222"
    case .Failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}

//I want to wait for request1's response and get the new token value.
let URLString2 = "http://httpbin.org/get?token=\(token)"
Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString2, parameters:  nil, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success(let JSON):
        print("http2: \(JSON)")
        print("token: \(token)")
    case .Failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I don't want to put request2 in request1's success.
So now my solution is: I give a variable named tokenChange.I have a array to store all the request that need the token. When the token is changed , I send them one by one from the array. But this solution is not elegant.
So is there a good pattern to control this ?

Answer (score 0):

I find this method `dispatch_semaphore_signal`.It can solve my problem. So any other way ?

```
var token = "111111"

let group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) { () -> Void in
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    //token is 111111
    let URLString = "http://httpbin.org/get?token=\(token)"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters:  nil, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("http1: \(JSON)--class:")
            token = "222222"
            print("\n")
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    //token is 222222
    let URLString2 = "http://httpbin.org/get?token=\(token)"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString2, parameters:  nil, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("http2: \(JSON)--class:")
            print("\n")
            print ("token is:\(token)")
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    //token is 2222222
    let URLString3 = "http://httpbin.org/get?token=\(token)"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString3, parameters:  nil, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            //                    token = (JSON["args"]!!["value"]) as! String
            print("http3: \(JSON)--class:")
            print("\n")
            print ("token is:\(token)")
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) { () -> Void in
    NSLog("finish");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute the second url string inside the first request because the response will came in background thread so your code will be like this:

```
 var token = "111111111111"
    let URLString1 = "http://httpbin.org/get?token=\(token)"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString1, parameters:  nil, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("http1: \(JSON)")
            token = "22222222222"
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }


    let URLString2 = "http://httpbin.org/get?token=\(token)"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString2, parameters:  nil, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("http2: \(JSON)")
            print("token: \(token)")
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: If I send 10 requests at the same time. The other 9 requests all need first request's response. This solution can't be elegant. Any ideas?

Comment: so i suggest to set boolean var (responsed)  to false and include the other requests to while responsed variable will be true, and when the first requests response change the boolean variable (responsed) to true. i hope this will help

Comment: Yeah, this solution can be solved problem .But I don't think it is very elegant. XD